# Exporting levels within a data.frame to csv

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

```
#creating dataframe    
df1=data.frame(c("Mary","Sarah","Linda","Mark","Shaun","Jo"),c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c(2,2,2,1,1,2))
names(df1)=c("a","b","c")
#setting levels and labels for questions b and c
blevels=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
blabels=c("bike","walk","car","bus","train","subway")
clevels=c(1,2)
clabels=c("male","female")
#creating labelled data.frame
df2=df1
#applying labels
df2$b<-factor(df1$b,blevels,blabels)
df2$c<-factor(df1$c,clevels,clabels)
```

I am using R to create frequency tables for survey responses and use value labels to create more useful frequency tabels.

I also edit the data in R before the frequency tables are created to remove invalid values and use write.csv to export the data.frame for reference.

I want the exported data.frame to show the coding for each question rather than it's label. Currently to do this I create a new labelled data.frame for the frequencies and export the original data.frame.

This leads to the danger of differences between the reference and analysis data.frames.

Is there a way of exporting the levels rather than the labels to a csv file?

Comment: Have you tried the `foreign` package?  You can write SPSS files directly.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I want to do, I used to use SPSS and am now looking to replicate the same analysis process in R. I have edited my question to remove the SPSS reference as it probably confused things.

Comment: If you plan to analyse a lot of survey data, you should look at my (as yet unpublished) packages on GitHUB: https://github.com/andrie/surveydata and https://github.com/andrie/surveyor

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to strip the levels from a single vector:

```
f <- function(x) {
   if(is.factor(x)) {
      return(as.numeric(x))
   } else {
      return(x)
   }
}
```

Apply that function to the data.frame:

```
df <- sapply(f,df)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to print the data.frame showing only its value labels, not to remove the value labels from the original data.frame.

Comment: You wanted "levels rather than labels".  If you eant the labels instead, change as.numeric to as.character.